# Wrapping Datascript query in a function?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, datalog, datascript

Getting a seemingly bizarre problem with Datascript. For some reason when I run this query without it being wrapped in a function, everything works. But once I wrap it in a function, it returns the value for :block/content for every entity in the database. I'm confused because I haven't encountered any issues with wrapping other Datascript queries in the past. Does anyone more experienced than me with Datascript see any issues?

```
;; Works fine and returns the correct value
(ds/q '[:find ?block-text
        :where
        [?id :block/id "l_63xa4m1"]
        [?id :block/content ?block-text]]
      @conn)

;; Returns every value for `:block/content` in the db
(defn content-find
  [id-passed]
  (ds/q '[:find ?block-text
          :where
          [?id :block/id ?id-passed]
          [?id :block/content ?block-text]]
        @conn))
(content-find "l_63xa4m1")
```

**EDIT:** Solved over [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/gt2s50/wrapping_datascript_query_in_a_function/)

Comment: If you x-post and found an answer somewhere else: it's perfectly fine to provide your own answer to your question on SO and accept that, if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `defn` version you are using the query clause `[?id :block/id ?id-passed]`. This doesn't actually use the `id-passed` parameter you passed to the function.

I'm not sure how to pass parameters correctly. I believe there is an `:in` clause or so?

Comment: That would make sense, but I have another function that wraps a query with the same exact structure and works fine. The only difference is it's looking for the value of a different attribute.

Comment: Solved over here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/gt2s50/wrapping_datascript_query_in_a_function/